# debug CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS url?

Tags: c++, sqlite, libcurl

curl newbie, I am setting CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS options in c++ api and once the json syntax works I am not getting any result from rqlite database sql command. It worked in command line with -d flag.

```
url_flags = "\"[\\\"INSERT INTO foo2 values(1,11)\\\"]\"";
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, url_flags.c_str());
```

Is there a way to see the output url so I can try that in commandline?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I joined their mailing list and stand corrected:

The data you set with CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS is not part of the URL - it is part
of the request body - so seeing the URL won't help you.

You can see the URL with CURLOPT_VERBOSE set to 1L, but since you probably
rather see the request body so that you get to see what you post you want to
add a CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION callback and show the data that way.

Possibly based on this example code: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/debug.html

Alternatively, you make a command line version of the request with curl that
works and then you convert that to libcurl code with the "--libcurl code.c"
option